# Deserialize unnamed json array into an object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

Wondering how to deserialize the following string in c#:

```
"[{\"access_token\":\"thisistheaccesstoken\"}]"
```

I know how to do it if the json was:

```
"{array=[{\"access_token\":\"thisistheaccesstoken\"}]}"
```

I'd do it like this:

```
public class AccessToken
{
    public string access_token {get;set;}
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }
}

public class TokenReturn
{
    public List<AccessToken> tokens { get; set; }
}

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
TokenReturn result = ser.Deserialize<TokenReturn>(responseFromServer);
```

But without that array name, I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The second example is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, Just did it with:

```
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<AccessToken> result = ser.Deserialize<List<AccessToken>>(jsonString);
```